Python: Own package not recognized
I have an issue where I dont get the solution.
I also look here in stackoverflow.com, tried different solutions but nothing helps.
My project struct looks like this:
-MyFolder
----MySubFolder
------MySubFolder.py
------__init__.py
----MyFolder.py
----__init__.py

To be clear. MyFolder.py and his init.py are below MyFolder and above MySubFolder.
In a different project, I import MyFolder, but PyCharm doesn´t recognized MyFolder as a Package.
MyFolder is part of PYTHONPATH, so it should be found.
In the init.py inside MyFolder, it looks like:
import os
import sys
fpath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.append(fpath)

from MyFolder import *

and in MySubFolder
import os
import sys
fpath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.append(fpath)

from MySubFolder import *

But when I do
from MyFolder.MyFolder import *

then it working.
But my goal is only to import MyFolder

sys.path modifications are very often not necessary, rather a red flag. I would remove all of them if I were you. There is very likely a much simpler way to achieve what you want to do. -- It would be better if you used clearer names for your example. Having a MyFolder directory and a MyFolder.py file make things very hard to follow.

Have you tried installing your package into your virtual environment, as a pop editable install?

The are two ways to layout a Python project, often referred to as "flat" and "src". https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/src-layout-vs-flat-layout/ . You have gone for the src layout which requires installation of the project to be able to run its code, rather than the flat layout which does not. This means that the src layout involves an additional step in the development workflow of a project (typically, an editable installation is used for development and a regular installation is used for testing).
